# ExtJS styles have errors (when the page is scaled) / Styles Bug

Tags: extjs, styles

**Steps to Reproduction**: Just open [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com) and run the simplest code with the `Classic Neptune` theme, and then try to zoom in or out with your browser.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if anyone else has found the same problem and if this can be fixed?

EDITED:
`Classic Triton/Graphite` theme also has this bug.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.x-window.x-window-default.x-border-box {
  background: #3892d4 !important;
}
```